# Connecting to OrientDB from Spark in Java

Tags: apache-spark

Have been trying to get a working database connection to OrientDB (v2.1.16) from my Java-based Spark (v2.0.0) code but had no luck so far.

The only available connector specifically for OrientDB/Spark seems to only work with Scala code: https://github.com/metreta/spark-orientdb-connector
Since Java and Scala both execute on the JVM I imagine it should be possible to use it from Java but haven't seen how.

OrientDB has a JDBC driver and I have also tried that route:

```
 SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("My Spark App").getOrCreate();

 Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String,String>();
 options.put("driver", "com.orientechnologies.orient.jdbc.OrientJdbcDriver");
 options.put("url", "jdbc:orient:remote:192.168.1.2/mydb");
 options.put("dbtable", "Customer");
 options.put("user", "user");
 options.put("password", "password");

 Dataset< org.apache.spark.sql.Row> df = spark.read().format("jdbc").options(options).load();
```

This gives an error on all queries I've tried (supplying Spark with the OrientDB JDBC jar in spark-submit):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No current record
at com.orientechnologies.orient.jdbc.OrientJdbcResultSetMetaData.getCurrentRecord(OrientJdbcResultSetMetaData.java:202)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.jdbc.OrientJdbcResultSetMetaData.getColumnCount(OrientJdbcResultSetMetaData.java:84)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:130)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:117)
```

Has anyone successfully accomplished this?

Comment: Did Srinu's solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Github project that seems to be for connecting Spark with OrientDB:

https://github.com/metreta/spark-orientdb-connector/blob/master/spark-orientdb-connector/src/test/scala/com/metreta/spark/orientdb/connector/rdd/GraphRDDSpec.scala

You could also just use the HTTP (REST) API with JSON formatted data.

http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/OrientDB-REST.html (note: not the latest version of the docs)

Comment: Both the OP and the comment already link to that package. Did it work for you with Spark 2.0?

Comment: No luck with Spark 1.6.x or 2.0.0 yet. OrientDB support is also looking at the issue for me. As previously stated, that connector on Github does not suite my needs since it won't work from Java. They are however promising Java support within a couple of months.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following dependency:

```
<dependency> 
<groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId> 
<artifactId>orientdb-jdbc
</artifactId>
 <version>2.2.10</version>
</dependency>
```

The following code works fine for me:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
conf.setMaster("local");
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Orient_Spark_Session").config(conf).getOrCreate();
Map<String, String> orientDBProps = new HashMap<>(); 
orientDBProps.put("url","jdbc:orient:REMOTE:localhost/TestDB");
orientDBProps.put("user", "root");
orientDBProps.put("password", "root");
orientDBProps.put("spark", "true");
orientDBProps.put("dbtable", "test");
Dataset<Row> tableDataset = spark.read().format("jdbc").options(dbProps).load();
tableDataset.show();
```